# python pandas, csv imports as a single column

Tags: pandas, csv

Hi I've tried to find similar, answered questions before sending this.

Im importing a csv into Jupyter, and it seems to import as a single column, with 800 rows and 1 column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('pokemon_data.csv')
df.head()
```

[image]

where as the same method on another file, works exactly as expected.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a link or sample of the data for each instance?

Comment: make use of the keyword arguments in the function call `pd.read_csv('pokemon_data.csv',sep=',')` I think the newer versions of pandas make use of CSVSniffer to find the sep so it wont always be 100% i can't replicate your issue here as well. Can you post a few lines of the raw csv? open it up with a text editor and paste it in.

Comment: Here is the first 9 line of the csv file.
"#,Name,Type 1,Type 2,HP,Attack,Defense,Sp. Atk,Sp. Def,Speed,Generation,Legendary"
"1,Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,45,49,49,65,65,45,1,FALSE"
"2,Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,60,62,63,80,80,60,1,FALSE"
"3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,80,82,83,100,100,80,1,FALSE"
"3,VenusaurMega Venusaur,Grass,Poison,80,100,123,122,120,80,1,FALSE"
"4,Charmander,Fire,,39,52,43,60,50,65,1,FALSE"
"5,Charmeleon,Fire,,58,64,58,80,65,80,1,FALSE"
"6,Charizard,Fire,Flying,78,84,78,109,85,100,1,FALSE"
"6,CharizardMega Charizard X,Fire,Dragon,78,130,111,130,85,100,1,FALSE"

Answer (score 0):

Using this data that was in the comments:

```
#,Name,Type 1,Type 2,HP,Attack,Defense,Sp. Atk,Sp. Def,Speed,Generation,Legendary 
1,Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,45,49,49,65,65,45,1,FALSE
2,Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,60,62,63,80,80,60,1,FALSE
3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,80,82,83,100,100,80,1,FALSE
3,Mega Venusaur,Grass,Poison,80,100,123,122,120,80,1,FALSE 
4,Charmander,Fire,,39,52,43,60,50,65,1,FALSE
5,Charmeleon,Fire,,58,64,58,80,65,80,1,FALSE
```

And using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('pokemon.csv',sep=',')
print(df.head())
```

Yields the following results

```
   #           Name Type 1  Type 2  HP  Attack  Defense  Sp. Atk  Sp. Def  Speed  Generation Legendary 
0  1      Bulbasaur  Grass  Poison  45      49       49       65       65     45           1      FALSE
1  2        Ivysaur  Grass  Poison  60      62       63       80       80     60           1      FALSE
2  3       Venusaur  Grass  Poison  80      82       83      100      100     80           1      FALSE
3  3  Mega Venusaur  Grass  Poison  80     100      123      122      120     80           1     FALSE
4  4     Charmander   Fire     NaN  39      52       43       60       50     65           1      FALSE
```

Comment: Did you set the encoding for your Pokemon.csv? Otherwise not sure why this is happening?